# how to fix: "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python, string, for-loop, integer

im new to python, still learning it and im trying to make a script that sends out emails to multiple emails but im having a problem with it. it keeps on printing out an error in line 9:

"list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

and im confused on what that means and what i need to do to fix that.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

email_list = ["First@email.com", "second@email.com", "third@email.com", "etc..."]

num = 0
for i in email_list:
    msg['To'] = email_list[i] #this line gives the error
    num = num + 1
    server.sendmail(email, email_list[i], text)

print("Emails Sent: " + num)
```

I expect the output to be, Emails Sent: 3, but it doesn't lol

Comment: `msg['To'] = ...` is supposed to do what?  `msg` is undefined.

Comment: msg = MIMEMultipart()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python `for e in C` must be read as 'for each element e of the collection C', meaning that at each iteration `e` takes the value of a different element of the collection `C`.

In your example, `i` will take the values "First@email.com" then "second@email.com" etc.. and not 0, 1... as you seem to believe.
However when you're doing `email_list[i]` you're trying to get the i'th value of your list. Which doesn't works since we saw that `i` is a string.

Comment: i see what you mean, so all i would need to do is change i into a string?

Comment: i'm sorry i mean integer

Comment: @Merced you should use `i` directly, it already holds the value you're looking for. (instead of `email_list[i]`). You don't need to think about indices and such.

Comment: i do want to say, thank you so much for all this information, im learning alot just from this convo but how would type that? like what would the syntax be for that.

Comment: @Merced line 9`msg['To'] = i`, line 10 `num = num + 1` line 11 `server.sendmail(email, i, text)`